# Concavity of the log of a simple equation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Consider the following function
$$
f(x,y)=\log\left(1 - \frac{x}{1+y} -\frac{y}{1+x} \right)
$$
defined on $0\leq x\leq1$ and $0\leq y\leq1$. The plot of this function looks quite concave but I would like a proof. Ideally without using the Hessian directly so I can generalize the argument easily. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's strange because the function $g(y) = 1-\frac{x_0}{1+y}-\frac{y}{1+x_0}$ for fixed $x_0$ is not necessarily nonincreasing. What is more, the Hessian of $f$ is a rather complex function.

Comment: One more though: if $g$ where concave, because of the fact that every nonnegative concave function is log-concave, $f$ would be concave. However, $g$ is not concave (neither is it convex).

Comment: $g$ looks actually concave for $y\geq 0$. It's not always decreasing however.

Comment: $g$ is not concave for $x,y\in [0,1]$. Take the line which is defined by $y=x$.  Then $g(x,x)=1-\frac{2x}{x+1}$ is convex.

Comment: Good catch. That was not obvious from the plot. The log of $g$ is concave though.